# Continuous Deployment of a NestJs Application to Heroku

Tags: git, heroku, nestjs, circleci

So I'm trying to use CircleCi to deploy my NestJs application to Heroku, but the CircleCi build keeps falling and I can't exactly figure out why.

I followed the steps in this article https://circleci.com/blog/continuous-deployment-nestjs/ but still can't seem to make the build pass

Here's a log of the error.
NB: I have added **environment variables**, **Procfile** and updated the port in my **main.ts**

````
if false;then
  force="-f"
fi
git push $force https://heroku:$HEROKU_API_KEY@git.heroku.com/$HEROKU_APP_NAME.git $CIRCLE_BRANCH:master
remote: !   WARNING:
remote: !   Do not authenticate with username and password using git.
remote: !   Run `heroku login` to update your credentials, then retry the git command.
remote: !   See documentation for details: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#http-git-authentication
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://git.heroku.com/.git/'

Exited with code exit status 128
CircleCI received exit code 128```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check your environment variables again. Don't forget that your variables should be named as:
HEROKU_APP_NAME and
HEROKU_API_KEY, respectively.

Comment: Thank you, that was my mistake, wrong env variables naming